# vba - loop through 3 columns

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

There are 4 columns on my excel.

For every element in column A, I would like to loop through every element column C. If the element in column C equal to column A, then it return the value of column D in column B.

For example, B4 should return "dog". B5 should return "egg". B6 should return "cat".

[image]

[image]

I ran my VBA code. All the value in column B returns "egg". Could someone have a look with my below VBA code please?

```
Sub testing_click()

Dim x As Variant
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim i , r As Long
arr1 = Worksheets("testing").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value


For Each x In arr1
    For r = 1 To 5
    If x = Trim(Worksheets("testing").Cells(r, "c").Value) Then
        For i = 1 To Worksheets("testing").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("testing").Cells(i, "b").Value = Worksheets("testing").Cells(r, "d").Value
        Next i
    End If
    Next r
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there some reason why VLOOKUP won't work in your situation?  I.e. `=vlookup(A1, C:D, 2, False) `.

Comment: Hi Michael, I actually need it to build my vba for outlook in order to add multiple reciepents in an array. So I break down my question into simpler example.

Comment: Fair enough.  Looks like you got a couple of options, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had one too many loops in there.  What it was actually doing was finding the first value correctly, and putting it in all 12 rows of column "B".  Then finding the second value, and re-assigning all 12 rows of column "B".

Get rid of the innermost loop, add counter in it's place with the same name, and you're good to go.  Now, instead of looking through all cells in column "A", it only looks through the populated ones, and will terminate the inner loop as soon as it has a match.

Also corrected a mistake in the declarations.  `Dim i, r As Long` actually only casts `r` as long, and `i` as Variant.  `Dim i as Long, r as Long` will capture them both as Long types.

Hope it helps!

```
Sub testing_click()

Dim x As Variant
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim i as Long, r As Long
arr1 = Worksheets("testing").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

'initialize row counter out here
i = 1
For Each x In arr1
    For r = 1 To 5
        If x = Trim(Worksheets("testing").Cells(r, "c").Value) Then
            Worksheets("testing").Cells(i, "b").Value = Worksheets("testing").Cells(r, "d").Value
            'Increment row counter and exit inner loop
            i = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help!  For posterity, @MikeD put up a really great solution too.  Really pretty way to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have another question regarding loop table. I would really appreciate if you have a look when you have time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037004/vba-copy-a-specific-format-table-from-outlook-to-email

Answer (score 2):

arr1 must be Dim'ed as array ... e.g. `Dim arr1() As Variant`

I also recommend to substitute the `End(xlUpDownLeftRightHomeEnd)`'s by more VBA like loop constructs, e.g.

```
Sub ClassicalLoops()
Dim OuterLoop As Integer, InnerLoop As Integer
Dim DataRange As Range, LookupRange As Range

    Set DataRange = [A1]
    Set LookupRange = [C1]

    OuterLoop = 1
    Do While DataRange(OuterLoop, 1) <> ""
        InnerLoop = 1
        Do While LookupRange(InnerLoop, 1) <> ""
            If DataRange(OuterLoop, 1) = LookupRange(InnerLoop, 1) Then
                DataRange(OuterLoop, 2) = LookupRange(InnerLoop, 2)
                Exit Do
            Else
                InnerLoop = InnerLoop + 1
            End If
        Loop
        OuterLoop = OuterLoop + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! I can see why you name your sub classical loops. Learn a lot from it.