# Copy a specific format table from outlook to email

Tags: vba, html-table, outlook

I need to copy many tables from outlook to Excel at work.
I know how to use `.getElementsByTagName("table")`  to do it.
However, my company merges and split some of the table cells.
Could someone have a look on it please?

**This is the table I have in my outlook:**
[image]

**This is how I would like to copy it on my Excel:**

[image]

**This is the result:**

[image]

**VBA code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public fso As New FileSystemObject
Public objApp As Outlook.Application
Public oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Sub importOutlookTable()

 Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()

    oItem.display

Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
With oHTML
    .body.innerHTML = oItem.HTMLBody
    Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With

'import in Excel
Dim x As Long, y As Long

With Worksheets("sheet2")
For x = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows.Length - 1
    For y = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
        .Range("a1").Offset(x, y).Value = oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
    Next y
Next x


End With

Set objApp = Nothing
Set oItem = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object

    Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

**html code on my outlook:**

```
</head>

<body lang="ZH-TW" link="#0563C1" style='text-justify-trim:punctuation' vlink=
"#954F72">
    <div class="WordSection1">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=
        "MsoNormalTable" style=
        'width:203.0pt;margin-left:.1pt;border-collapse:collapse' width="271">
            <tr style='height:15.75pt'>
                <td nowrap rowspan="2" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:15.75pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=
                    'font-weight: bold; text-align: center'><span lang="EN-US"
                    style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>header 1</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap style=
                'width:83.0pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:15.75pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=
                    'font-weight: bold; text-align: center'><span lang="EN-US"
                    style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>header 2</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="2" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:15.75pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=
                    'font-weight: bold; text-align: center'><span lang="EN-US"
                    style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>header 4</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="21" style='height:15.75pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:16.5pt'>
                <td nowrap style=
                'width:83.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:16.5pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style=
                    'font-weight: bold; text-align: center'><span lang="EN-US"
                    style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>header 3</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="22" style='height:16.5pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
                <td nowrap rowspan="3" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>apple</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="2" style=
                'width:83.0pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>red</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="3" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>4</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="24" style='height:18.0pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
                <td height="24" style='height:18.0pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:15.75pt'>
                <td nowrap style=
                'width:83.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:15.75pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>fruit</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="21" style='height:15.75pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
                <td nowrap rowspan="3" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>banana</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="2" style=
                'width:83.0pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>yellow</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="3" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>3</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="24" style='height:18.0pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
                <td height="24" style='height:18.0pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:15.75pt'>
                <td nowrap style=
                'width:83.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:15.75pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>fruit</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="21" style='height:15.75pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
                <td nowrap rowspan="3" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>cat</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="2" style=
                'width:83.0pt;border:none;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>cute</span></p>
                </td>

                <td nowrap rowspan="3" style=
                'width:60.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:18.0pt'
                width="80">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style='font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>1</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="24" style='height:18.0pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:18.0pt'>
                <td height="24" style='height:18.0pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr style='height:15.75pt'>
                <td nowrap style=
                'width:83.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0cm 1.4pt 0cm 1.4pt;height:15.75pt'
                valign="bottom" width="111">
                    <p class="MsoNormal" style='text-align: center'><span lang=
                    "EN-US" style=
                    'font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'>animal</span></p>
                </td>

                <td height="21" style='height:15.75pt;border:none' width="0">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>

        <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>

        <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>

        <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>

        <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>

        <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any chance you can add the HTML behind the table from outlook to your post?

Comment: hi Michael, I have added html source code of my email.

Comment: hi michael, I understand there is lots of html code for you to read. If you could just show me how to do a couple of cells, I will try figure it out the rest by myself.

Comment: It's not too bad. I'm looking through it now.  Tall document, but not really much in there.

Comment: I think i see a simple way out of this (little code editing).  Is the 3rd column always numeric?  Do you really need 3 rows for each value under header1, or will two be enough?

Comment: 2 is fine under header 1 and 3rd column is always numeric. Just a reminder that it can't merge the cells under header 2 into 1 cell as i need the info of "red" and "fruit" separately.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  It breaks the elements out into a collection first, so you don't have to worry about the variation in `Cells.Length`.  In the HTML table some rows have 4 cells, and others have only one that spans the row 2x high. Which is why it wasn't populating your table properly

You'll have to reformat the target, but it will keep the data under Header 2 separate, and avoid the wasted rows.

[image]

Replace This:

```
With Worksheets("sheet2")
For x = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows.Length - 1
    For y = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
        .Range("a1").Offset(x, y).Value = oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
    Next y
Next x

End With
```

With This:

```
Dim colTabEle As New Collection
Dim i As Integer: i = 1

For x = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows.Length - 1
    For y = 0 To oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
        colTabEle.Add oElColl(0).Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
    Next y
Next x

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    For x = 0 To (colTabEle.Count + 1) / 4
        For y = 0 To 2
            .Range("a1").Offset(x, y).Value = colTabEle(i)
            If IsNumeric(colTabEle(i)) Then
                i = i + 2
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End With
```